# Difference between Application servers and standalone frameworks

Tags: java, soap, jboss, frameworks, application-server

I would like you guys to give me some feedback, on my understanding about the
 difference between Application Servers such as **JBoss** and frameworks such as **Axis** and **CXF**.

- **CXF** is a standalone, web-app based framework  that
  implements **JAX-RS**, **JAX-WS** API wich, in turn, are part of the
  larger API set of **JEE**.
  Being a web-app based implementation, it
  can only be used to host "**SOAP on HTTP**" services even if the
  standard **JAX-WS** defines other possible channels for **SOAP**
  messages,such as **SMTP**.
- Application servers,such as **JBOSS**, instead implement **JAX-WS** as well as all the other **JEE** APIs in a more "native" and direct way, so,for example, they can be used to host also **SOAP on SMTP** services.
- Both **AS** and standalone frameworks such as **CXF** and **AXIS** make
  extensive use of **Inversion of control**.
- Application Servers, such as **Jboss**, can be thought as composed by a
  set of frameworks that implement all the **JEE** stack API.

Please take some time to correct/enhance the above statements.

Thanks

Comment: Where (in your understanding) does a standalone framework function? A framework is a set of apis that can be used to build an application. An *application server* is something that can serve an *application*.

Comment: I've used CXF and AXIS as standalone framewoks packed as a web-app.

Comment: [Apache CXF - Application Server Specific Configuration Guide](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/application-server-specific-configuration-guide.html)... it has to be in some kind of an application server.